# downloading files from server using IntentService in android

Tags: android, download, intentservice

I am trying to download files using IntentService.My downloading queue is interrupted.

I am using the following code to start a service

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ViewShowList.this, DownloadService.class);
    // Create a new Messenger for the communication back
    Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
    intent.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    intent.putExtra("share_id", showID);
    intent.putExtra("showname", name);
    intent.putExtra("showdatecreated", dateCreated);
    intent.putExtra("noofFiles", noofFiles);
    startService(intent);
```

Handler for communication back

```
@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage.....................");
        //Object path = message.obj;
        if (message.arg1 == DownloadService.COMPLETED) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, getResources().getString(R.string.Text_MadeOffline), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            createOfflineShowsList();
            syncShowAssets();
            if (showListadapter != null) {
                showListadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed...");
        }
    }
};
```

DownloadService.java

This is service class which extend IntentService

```
public class DownloadService
extends IntentService {

private int OFFSET;
private int LIMIT;

String data;
private final String TAG = "DownloadService";
private int result = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;

public static int COMPLETED = 100;
public static int FAILED = 101;
public static int LOW_SPACE = 102;
public static int NETWORK_PROBLEM = 103;
public static int ASSERT_EXISIT = 104;
public static int PARTIALLY_DOWNLOADED = 105;
public static int NO_FILE = 105;

private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private Notification notification;
ConnectivityManager connMgr;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> showAssetList;

private SharedPreferences sotcPref;
PendingIntent contentIntent;
int i = 1;

String url;
String showname;
String showdatecreated;
String showId;
Messenger messenger;
int noofFiles;

public DownloadService() {
  super("DownloadService");
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 5 " + "DownloadService()constructor");
  }
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DownloadService... Constructor");
  }
  OFFSET = 0;
  LIMIT = 3;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 6 " + "onHandleIntent");
  }
  connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  sotcPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SOTCPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent.........");
  }
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  url = extras.getString("url");
  showname = extras.getString("showname");
  showdatecreated = extras.getString("showdatecreated");

  //sara
  if (showdatecreated.contains("/")) {
    data = showdatecreated.replaceAll("/", "#");
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      System.out.println("date");
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      System.out.println(data);
    }
  } else {
    data = showdatecreated;
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      System.out.println("date in else");
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      System.out.println(showdatecreated);
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      System.out.println(data);
    }
  }
  showId = extras.getString("share_id");
  noofFiles = extras.getInt("noofFiles");

  messenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
  contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
  notification = new Notification(R.drawable.sotc_notification_icon, "", System.currentTimeMillis());
  notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
  notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
    .getPackageName(), R.layout.upload_progress_bar);
  notification.icon = R.drawable.sotc_notification_icon;
  notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, showname);
  notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
  notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100, 0, false);
  notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.i("FOO", "Notification started");
  }

  if (showname.length() > 18) {
    showname = showname.substring(0, 17);
  }

  if (DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT == 0) {

    downloadSetofAssets(OFFSET, LIMIT, url);
    if (DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT > LIMIT) {
      if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 8 " + "if(DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT > LIMIT)");
      }
      for (OFFSET = LIMIT; OFFSET < DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT; ) {
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 8.1 " + "if(DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT > LIMIT)");
        }
        downloadSetofAssets(OFFSET, LIMIT, url);
        OFFSET = OFFSET + LIMIT;
      }
    }
  }

  if (i > 1) {
    result = DownloadService.COMPLETED;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(DownloadService.this, "Downloaded Successfully", "", contentIntent);
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.arg1 = result;
    try {
      messenger.send(msg);
    } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
      if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
      }
    }

  } else {
    result = DownloadService.FAILED;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(DownloadService.this, "Downloaded Failed", "", contentIntent);
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      Log.e(TAG, "Download Failed...");
    }

  }
  notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
  notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
  notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}

private void downloadSetofAssets(int OFFSET, int LIMIT, String url) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 7 " + "downloadSetofAssets");
  }
  try {
    url = url.replace("value1", URLEncoder.encode("" + OFFSET, "UTF-8"));
    url = url.replace("value2", URLEncoder.encode("" + LIMIT, "UTF-8"));
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Show offline -- Asset URL: " + url);
  }
  showAssetList = DownloadAssets.hit(getApplicationContext(), url);

  for (HashMap<String, String> asset : showAssetList) {

    String thumbUrl = asset.get("thumb_url");
    String normalUrl = asset.get("normal_url");
    String mp4Url = asset.get("mp4_url");
    String fileType = asset.get("filetype");
    String assetID = asset.get("id");
    String assetType = asset.get("asset_type");

    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Thumb Url :" + thumbUrl);
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Normal Url :" + normalUrl);
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Asset ID : " + assetID);
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Asset Type : " + assetType);
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(TAG, "MP4 Url : " + mp4Url);
    }
    if (Constants.DEBUG) {
      Log.d(TAG, "FileType : " + fileType);
    }

    boolean isDownloaded = false;

    if (assetType.equals("1")) {       // Image
      File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId, showname, data, assetID, assetType);
      if (assetDirectory != null) {
        File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb");
        thumb.mkdirs();

        // Thumbnail
        File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Thumb File ath : " + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, thumbUrl, thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

        File normal = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal");
        normal.mkdirs();

        // Normal
        File normalFile = new File(normal.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal." + getExtention(normalUrl));
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Normal File path: " + normalFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, normalUrl, normalFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

      }
    } else if (assetType.equals("2")) {   // Video
      File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId, showname, data, assetID, assetType);
      if (assetDirectory != null) {
        if (!fileType.equals("Youtube")) { // via AddLink
          File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb");
          thumb.mkdirs();

          // Thumbnail
          File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Thumb File ath : " + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
          }
          isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, thumbUrl, thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

          File mp4url = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal");
          mp4url.mkdirs();

          // mp4_Url
          File mp4File = new File(mp4url.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal." + getExtention(mp4Url));
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Normal File path: " + mp4File.getAbsolutePath());
          }
          isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, mp4Url, mp4File.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);
        } else if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Asset type is video but is Youtube link. So not proceeding for offline");
        }

      }
    } else if (assetType.equals("3")) {   // Audio
      File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId, showname, data, assetID, assetType);
      if (assetDirectory != null) {

        File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb");
        thumb.mkdirs();

        // Thumbnail
        File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Thumb File ath : " + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, thumbUrl, thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

        File normal = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal");
        normal.mkdirs();
        // Normal
        File normalFile = new File(normal.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal." + getExtention(normalUrl));
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.d(TAG, "Normal File path: " + normalFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, normalUrl, normalFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

      }
    } else {
      if (!assetType.equals("5")) {
        File assetDirectory = createAssetDirectory(showId, showname, data, assetID, assetType);
        if (assetDirectory != null) {
          File thumb = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb");
          thumb.mkdirs();

          // Thumbnail
          File thumbFile = new File(thumb.getAbsolutePath(), "/Thumb." + getExtention(thumbUrl));
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Thumb File ath : " + thumbFile.getAbsolutePath());
          }
          isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, thumbUrl, thumbFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

          File normal = new File(assetDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal");
          normal.mkdirs();

          // Normal
          File normalFile = new File(normal.getAbsolutePath(), "/Normal." + getExtention(normalUrl));
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Normal File path: " + normalFile.getAbsolutePath());
          }
          isDownloaded = doInBackground(this, normalUrl, normalFile.getAbsolutePath(), messenger);

        } else { //"5" Link
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "This is Web Link");
          }
          isDownloaded = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}


private String getLoginFolders() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  File file = null;
  int status = Constants.getSDCardStatus();
  if (status == Constants.MOUNTED) {
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
      "/SOTC_OFF/.nomedia");
    f.mkdirs();
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
      "/SOTC_OFF/" + sotcPref.getString("domain", "") + "/" + sotcPref.getString("user_id", ""));
    file.mkdirs();
  }

  return file.getAbsolutePath();
}


private File createAssetDirectory(String showid, String showname,
                                  String data, String assetID, String assetType) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 10 " + "createAssetDirectory");
  }
  File file = null;
  int status = Constants.getSDCardStatus();
  if (status == Constants.MOUNTED) {
    if (DownloadAssets.TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT != 0) {
      /**
       * From to concept here is to avoid duplication of new
       * offline shows when show is updated. So, we are here
       * renaming previous offline show's folder name with
       * updated asset count.
       */

      boolean isRenameSuccess = false;
      File f = new File(getLoginFolders());
      if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdirs();
      }
      File[] fileArray = f.listFiles();
      File f2 = new File(getLoginFolders(), "/"
        + showid.trim() + ","
        + showname.trim() + ","
        + data);

      for (File from : fileArray) {
        String s1 = from.getName().substring(0, from.getName().lastIndexOf(","));
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.i(TAG, "s1: " + s1);
        }
        if (f2.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(s1)) {
          //Rename
          File to = new File(getLoginFolders(), "/"
            + showid.trim() + ","
            + showname.trim() + ","
            + data + ","
            + noofFiles);
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "from existence: " + from.exists());
          }

          try {
            isRenameSuccess = from.renameTo(to);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "isRenameSuccess: " + isRenameSuccess);
          }
          break;
        }
      }

      file = new File(getLoginFolders(), "/"
        + showid.trim() + ","
        + showname.trim() + ","
        + data + ","
        + noofFiles +
        "/File_"
        + assetID + ","
        + assetType.trim());
    }

    if (file != null) {
      if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
      }
    }
  }
  return file;
}

public static String getExtention(String url) {
  String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
  return extension;
}

@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "deprecation"})
boolean doInBackground(Context context, String urlPath, String destinationPath, Messenger messenger) {
  boolean isDownloaded = false;
  int lastPercent = 0;

  File destination = new File(destinationPath);
  if (!destination.exists()) {

    if (chkConnectionStatus()) {
      InputStream stream = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      try {

        URL imageUrl = new URL(urlPath);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        stream = conn.getInputStream();
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.i(TAG, "contentLength : " + contentLength);
        }

        if (contentLength == 0) {
          result = DownloadService.NO_FILE;
          destination.delete();
          isDownloaded = false;
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Text_NoFile), 1000).show();
        } else if (contentLength > availablestorageOnExternalDir()) {
          //No Space Available
          result = DownloadService.LOW_SPACE;
          destination.delete();
          isDownloaded = false;
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.Text_NoSpaceShow), 1000).show();
        } else {
          fos = new FileOutputStream(destination.getPath());
          long total = 0l;
          final int buffer_size = 4 * 1024;
          try {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
            for (; ; ) {
              int count = stream.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if (count == -1) {
                break;
              }
              fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
              total += count;
              int percent = (int) ((total * 100) / contentLength);
              if (percent > lastPercent) {
                notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar1, 100, percent, false);
                lastPercent = percent;
              }
            }
            if (destination.length() < contentLength) {
              result = DownloadService.PARTIALLY_DOWNLOADED;
              destination.delete();
              isDownloaded = false;
            } else {

              if (Constants.DEBUG) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Sucessful downloaded-------------------------------------------------" + i++);
              }
              // Sucessful finished
              //i++;
              result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
              isDownloaded = true;
            }
          } catch (Exception ex) {

          }
        }
        conn.disconnect();

        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.arg1 = result;
        msg.obj = destination.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
          messenger.send(msg);
        } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
          }
        }
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.v(TAG, "Completed.............. ");
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
          try {
            stream.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
        if (fos != null) {
          try {
            fos.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      /// no network connection
      result = DownloadService.NETWORK_PROBLEM;
      notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Please check your network connection", "", contentIntent);
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
      notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
      isDownloaded = true;
      Message msg = Message.obtain();
      msg.arg1 = result;
      msg.obj = destination.getAbsolutePath();
      try {
        messenger.send(msg);
      } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
        if (Constants.DEBUG) {
          Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
        }
      }
    }

  } else {
    result = DownloadService.ASSERT_EXISIT;
    Message msg = Message.obtain();
    msg.arg1 = result;
    msg.obj = destination.getAbsolutePath();
    try {
      messenger.send(msg);
    } catch (android.os.RemoteException e1) {
      if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.w(getClass().getName(), "Exception sending message", e1);
      }
    }
    isDownloaded = true;
  }
  return isDownloaded;
}

public long availablestorageOnExternalDir() //Get Available space(in Bytes)
{
  StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
  long bytesAvailable = (long) stat.getBlockSize() * (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks();
  long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / (1024 * 1024);
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.e("", "Available MB : " + megAvailable);
  }
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.e("", "Available Bytes : " + bytesAvailable);
  }
  return bytesAvailable;
}

public boolean chkConnectionStatus() {

  final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
  final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =
    connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

  if (wifi.isAvailable()) {
    if (wifi.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else if (mobile.isAvailable()) {
    if (mobile.isConnected()) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}

}
```

DownloadAssets.java

```
//To download
//files into
//created folders
public class DownloadAssets {

private static final String TAG = "DownloadAssets";
public static int TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT;

static synchronized ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hit(Context context, String url) {
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 9 " + "hit url" + url);
  }
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

  String message = null;
  String result = null;

  try {
    result = Constants.queryRESTurl(url);

    if (result != null) {
      if (result.equals("timeout")) {
        message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Text_TimeOut);
      } else {
        JSONObject json = Constants.convertStringtoJsonObject(result);

        try {
          JSONObject results = json.getJSONObject(ThumbnailFragment.JSON_RESPONSE_ATTR_RESULTSET);
          String totalAssetCount = results.getString(ThumbnailFragment.JSON_RESPONSE_ATTR_ASSET_COUNT);
          TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT = Integer.parseInt(totalAssetCount);
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.i("5" + TAG, "totalAssetCount : " + totalAssetCount);
          }
          if (TOTAL_ASSET_COUNT != 0) {
            JSONArray assetData = results.getJSONArray(ThumbnailFragment.JSON_RESPONSE_ATTR_ASSET_ARRAY);

            if (Constants.DEBUG) {
              Log.i(TAG, "6Madhu " + assetData.toString());
            }
            int nObjects = assetData.length();
            if (Constants.DEBUG) {
              Log.i(TAG, "7Madhu " + nObjects);
            }
            if (nObjects != 0) {
              for (int i = 0; i < nObjects; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = assetData.getJSONObject(i);
                map.put("id", "" + e.getString("assets_id"));
                map.put("asset_name", "" + e.getString("asset_name"));
                map.put("thumb_url", "" + e.getString("thumb_url"));
                map.put("asset_type", "" + e.getString("asset_type"));
                map.put("large_url", "" + e.getString("large_url"));
                map.put("mp4_url", "" + e.getString("mp4_url"));
                map.put("normal_url", "" + e.getString("normal_url"));
                map.put("description", "" + e.getString("description"));
                map.put("filetype", "" + e.getString("filetype"));
                map.put("filename", "" + e.getString("original_filename"));
                map.put("filesize", "" + e.getString("filesize"));

                mList.add(map);
                if (Constants.DEBUG) {
                  Log.i(TAG, "Size in Loop " + mList.size());
                }
              }
            } else if (Constants.DEBUG) {
              Log.i(TAG, "EXECUTING ELSE nObjects");
            }

          } else if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "EXECUTING ELSE count");
          }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("8log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
          }
          message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Text_InvalidResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          if (Constants.DEBUG) {
            Log.e("8log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
          }
          message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Text_InvalidResponse);
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (Constants.DEBUG) {
        Log.i(TAG, "EXECUTING ELSE result");
      }
      message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Text_InvalidResponse);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    message = context.getResources().getString(R.string.Text_ServerProblem);
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Message : " + message);
  }
  if (Constants.DEBUG) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Offline step 9 End " + "hit return " + mList);
  }
  return mList;
}
}
```

My queries are 
Files are downloading but not all files at first time from server.If I download more folders for example Folder1,Folder2 then Folder3, Folder1 and Folder2 interrupted(i.e 1 file is downloaded) but Folder3 downloaded fully... 
How can I keep the queue of files/folders to be downloaded? !

Comment: You need to be more specific about why the downloads fail.

Comment: Hi HDave, I found the download failed scenario. But still interruption occured while downloading multiple folders.

Comment: What do you mean by "interrupted"?  What exactly was the exception?

Comment: @HDave Folder1 contains file11,file12....file1n and Folder2 contains file21,file22,....file2n . If I request to download one by one means in Folder1 files not fully downloaded and Folder2 downloaded fully.So request "download folder1" interrupted by the request "download folder2".

Comment: I am working in google nexus device. If I am click download button one by one last one is downloaded fully. But before the last one not fully downloaded.

Comment: I understand now, there is no exception, its that your event handler interrupts any in-progress downloads that are happening in the background.  Perhaps those background tasks are using global resources or other variables that are not thread-safe?

Comment: Don't know why its interrupted.Help need

Comment: @HDave IntentService doesn't maintain intent queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For speed up and maintaining the queue of intent follow the below approach

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    synchronized (intent) {


    final Intent intentCpy=intent;

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
//onHandleIntent code which is in question post

        }
    }
}
```

Use ConcurrentHashMap for Thread-Safty in following method

```
private synchronized  void downloadSetofAssets(int OFFSET , int LIMIT , String url)
```

for more details about ConcurrentHashMap please visit
http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2013/cmsc433/Notes/14-CMSC433-ConcurrentCollections.pdf